# Matching a binary string with 3 or more occurrences of '1'. Can this regex be improved? 

Tags: regex, binary

```
^[0-1]*1[0-1]*1[0-1]*1[0-1]*$
```

To match a binary string with 3 or more occurrences of '1'
This expression works...just trying to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match three or more occurrences of 1, I would use:

```
^(0*1){3}[01]*$
```

Comment: Note that you can change that three to anything, and you get that many '1's in the matches.

Comment: Sorry about confusion, my mistake i did mean at least 3 '1's

Comment: Change the last 0 to [01] and you're golden.

Comment: or use the `{3,}` syntax (means 3 or more)

Answer (score 1):

i think it'll be something like this, edited changed with alans suggestions

```
^(0*1){3,}0*$
```